# Why web api data deserialized from json returned as null and not displayed in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to JSON serialization and deserialization, currently trying to deserialize a set of data from a Web API call. The data is visible until the deserialization, but when it's sent to the view, it's showing "null".

Model:

```
public class Currency
{
    public string Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CurrencyController:Controller
{ 
    string Baseurl = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/";

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Currency CurencyInfo = new Currency();

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage Result = await client.GetAsync("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest");

            if (Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Storing the response details received from Web API 
                var CurrencyResponse = Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                // Deserializing the response received from Web API and storing into the CurrencyInfo 
                CurencyInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>((JObject.Parse(CurrencyResponse)["rates"]).ToString());
            }

            // returning the Currency Info to view  
            return View(CurencyInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your model doesn't match the data returned by that API.

Comment: CurrencyResponse is having all the returned values but after getting deserialized , CurrencyInfo returns null i.e Rates

Comment: Please update your question to add two bits of information. a) The exact value of `CurrencyResponse`. b) The exact value of `(JObject.Parse(CurrencyResponse)["rates"]).ToString()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window shows you how to get those values.

Comment: CurrencyResponse
"{\"rates\":{\"CAD\":1.4581,\"HKD\":8.7295,\"ISK\":139.3,\"PHP\":56.969,\"DKK\":7.4708,\"HUF\":329.92,\"CZK\":25.57,\"AUD\":1.6237,\"RON\":4.7609,\"SEK\":10.7303,\"IDR\":15626.52,\"INR\":78.9245,\"BRL\":4.59,\"RUB\":70.9699,\"HRK\":7.4405,\"JPY\":120.87,\"THB\":33.735,\"CHF\":1.1004,\"SGD\":1.5164,\"PLN\":4.2778,\"BGN\":1.9558,\"TRY\":6.4897,\"CNY\":7.8795,\"NOK\":10.1833,\"NZD\":1.7358,\"ZAR\":16.3337,\"USD\":1.113,\"MXN\":21.2721,\"ILS\":3.9411,\"GBP\":0.86065,\"KRW\":1305.83,\"MYR\":4.6618},\"base\":\"EUR\",\"date\":\"2019-10-22\"}"

Comment: Currencyinfo
{CurrencyInformer.Models.Currency}
    Rates: null

Comment: @Kunal checkout my answer. let me know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=lkvGz7FRx41PzeXkC2Hx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Currency Class is Incorrect.It does not include all the properties to bind.
Looking at the JSON result returned by https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest

Your Currency class should be as following:

```
public class Rates
{
    public double CAD { get; set; }
    public double HKD { get; set; }
    public double ISK { get; set; }
    public double PHP { get; set; }
    public double DKK { get; set; }
    public double HUF { get; set; }
    public double CZK { get; set; }
    public double AUD { get; set; }
    public double RON { get; set; }
    public double SEK { get; set; }
    public double IDR { get; set; }
    public double INR { get; set; }
    public double BRL { get; set; }
    public double RUB { get; set; }
    public double HRK { get; set; }
    public double JPY { get; set; }
    public double THB { get; set; }
    public double CHF { get; set; }
    public double SGD { get; set; }
    public double PLN { get; set; }
    public double BGN { get; set; }
    public double TRY { get; set; }
    public double CNY { get; set; }
    public double NOK { get; set; }
    public double NZD { get; set; }
    public double ZAR { get; set; }
    public double USD { get; set; }
    public double MXN { get; set; }
    public double ILS { get; set; }
    public double GBP { get; set; }
    public double KRW { get; set; }
    public double MYR { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public Rates rates { get; set; }

}
```

Your Action Method should be as following:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            Currency CurencyInfo = new Currency();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                Uri myUri = new Uri("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest", UriKind.Absolute);

                HttpResponseMessage Result = await client.GetAsync(myUri);

                if (Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var CurrencyResponse = Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the CurrencyInfo 
                    CurencyInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>((JObject.Parse(CurrencyResponse)).ToString());

                }

                //returning the Currency Info to view  
                return View(CurencyInfo);
            }

        }
```

**Note:** The class Rates contains all the properties returned by the API. Therefore, you can comment out any of the currencies whose data you do not require. I have tried this code and it works.

[image]

You can use any of the online tools like json2sharp to frame the classes / models for the JSON data you are looking to deserialize.

Comment: Thanks Although the issue is with ASP.net mvc and its still existing but you have shown me a way to tackle it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Rather than listing each individual currency, I'd suggest using https://app.quicktype.io?share=lkvGz7FRx41PzeXkC2Hx .

Comment: Thanks @mjwills but now  i am trying to display the data on a ASP.NET MVC  view, i am able to get the data in the controller but unable to transfer it to the view due to IEnumerable error.

Comment: @Kunal which approach you are using? The one I answered or the one recommended by @mjwills?

Comment: @Tango i am using the approach you have worked on but facing this error constantly "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CurrencyInformer.Models.Currency', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CurrencyInformer.Models.Currency]'." even after changing the model variables to ienumable type.. This error is after i adapted your approach.